# Required cushion/foam width to meet reduced force level in event of impact

Tags: forces, gravity, pressure

Suppose a biker is riding a bike and bumps into roadside. If he/she is wearing good cushioned helmet, will not feel high 'g' force, but with an average helmet, impact can be high. So how does width or quality of foam used, helps reduce the gravity impact? Is there any calculation to arrive at that ?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly experiments can be done; here are the objectives.

The objective of a helmet is twofold: 1) to prevent skull fracture and penetration  in the event of a point impact, and 2) to dissipate the impact energy over a finite impact duration to prevent the transmission of fatal G forces to the wearer's head.

So we instrument a cadaver head and drop it from head height onto a concrete slab with an indentor stuck in it, and measure the G forces and point-of-impact loads. Knowing those loads and forces we can then determine by how much *time* the impact event must be extended over to stay under the g-force lethality limit, and by how much *area* the impactor forces must be distributed to remain under the skull fracture limit.

Then we choose a *thick* deformable material with the right crushability to meet the max allowable g-force and a *thin, stiff* shell material with the right impact resistance to spread the impact load over enough skull area to prevent fracture.

The common result of this calculus is a *styrofoam* crush zone covered with a *fiber-reinforced resin* shell.